# Chrome WebNavigation Listener not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating my own extension for Google Chrome (for my own use, not to be published). At the moment I have two files:

**manifest.json**:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "abcdef",
  "description": "abcdef",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation",
    "http://www.ztm.waw.pl/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bg.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
}
```

**bg.js**:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(o) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(o.tabId, {
    code: "alert('ok');"
  });
}, {
  url: {
    hostContains: 'ztm.waw.pl'
  }
});
```

I want the alert box to appear when I navigate to http://www.ztm.waw.pl, but it does not work. Could someone tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url property of chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted accepts an array of chrome.events.UrlFilter ([source](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onCompleted)), so you'll need to change your bg.js to this (note the square and curly brackets in the url property):

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(o) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(o.tabId, {
    code: "alert('ok');"
  });
}, {
  url: [
    {hostContains: 'ztm.waw.pl'}
  ]
});
```

Comment: Gosh, I hate it when a small mistake makes the whole thing unusable. Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you please check my question too? I think I have a similar regex issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71501276/regex-filter-for-webnavigation-oncompleted-listener-not-working